# viability of alocacia seeds after winter storage

Tags: seed-saving, tropical

My climate is hot Mediterranean, winter temperatures seldom go below 5c/41F.

If I buy seeds around this time of the year (Midsummer), I must wait till the heat of summer abates, and winter is over, which gives me the first window of opportunity around March to April of next year. This means, the seeds will have to be stored in the fridge.

Do Alocacia seeds remain viable after this time in storage?

Comment: In general (and so not really an answer): read the instruction on the pack (and the "expiry" date). It seems a tropical plant, so I assume no fridge, Usually dry place is better, but I do not know anything about alocasia, so read pack or wait for real answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just wondering why you're buying Alocasia seeds and not corms/bulbs, because from seed, they take years before they produce the large leaves for which they are grown, see here https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/houseplants/alocasia-plant/elephant-ear-seed-pods.htm. There's also the difficulty of storing them till spring - seeds from this plant don't germinate easily, so having to keep them till next year might make that worse. I'd suggest you wait till early next year, buy a corm or two and start them off in pots around February time, then move outdoors later when they've grown on. Storing corms over winter is a lot easier - it's not dissimilar from storing dahlia tubers.